# Convert a tensorflow tf.data.Dataset FlatMapDataset to TensorSliceDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, vectorization, tensorflow-datasets

I want to pass a list of `tf.Strings` to the  `.map(_parse_function)` function.

```
 def _parse_function(self, img_path):
        img_str = tf.read_file(img_path)
        img_decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_str, channels=3)
        img_decode = tf.divide(tf.cast(img_decode , tf.float32),255)
        return img_decode
```

When the `tf.data.Dataset` is of type `TensorSliceDataset`,

```
dataset_from_slices = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tensor_with_filenames))
```

I can simply do
`dataset_from_slices.map(_parse_function`), which works.

However, `dataset_from_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)` returns a `Dataset` which is an instance of `FlatMapDataset` type and `dataset_from_generator.map(_parse_function)` gives the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input filename tensor must be scalar, but had shape: [32]
```

If I change the first line to:

```
img_str = tf.read_file(img_path[0])
```

that also works but then I only get the first image, which is not what I am looking for. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the elements of your `dataset_from_generator` are batched. The simplest remedy is to use `tf.contrib.data.unbatch()` to convert them back into individual elements:

```
# Each element is a vector of strings.
dataset_from_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(...)

# Converts each vector of strings into multiple individual elements.
dataset = dataset_from_generator.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

Comment: I have `import tensorflow as tf`. When I run `tf.contrib.data.unbatch()`, I get error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Comment: looks like we can call unbatch on `dataset_from_generator` in the latest version of Tensorflow i.e. 2.x+